# JQuery drop function is not being called

Tags: android, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have simple drag and drop functionality from one table to another which works well in how it looks but it appears my drop method is not being called.

here is the JQuery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

  var $tabs=$('#table-draggable2')
  $( "tbody.connectedSortable" )
    .sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        items: "> tr:not(:first)",
        appendTo: $tabs,
        helper:"clone",
        zIndex: 999990
    })
    .disableSelection();

   var $tab_items = $( ".nav-tabs > li", $tabs ).droppable(
   {
     accept: ".connectedSortable tr",
     hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",

     drop: function( event, ui ) 
    {
       alert("here!");
       return false;
    }
   });

   });
</script>
```

the css

```
ul li {
min-width: 200px;
}
.dragging li.ui-state-hover {
   min-width: 240px;
}
.dragging .ui-state-hover a {
   color:green !important;
   font-weight: bold;
}
th,td {
   text-align: right;
   padding: 2px 4px;
   border: 1px solid;
}
  .connectedSortable tr, .ui-sortable-helper {
  cursor: move;
}
.connectedSortable tr:first-child {
   cursor: default;
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
   background: yellow;
}
```

and the two tables just sets the ids

```
<table id='table-draggable1'
 ......
<table id='table-draggable2'
 .......
```

the drag and drop is visually working fine but i have placed an alert in drop method and it is never displayed, why is the drop method not called?

```
<table id='table-draggable1'>  
            <tbody class="connectedSortable">  
                <tr>
                    <th>col1</th>
                    <th>col2</th>  
                    <th>col3</th>  
                    <th>col4</th>  
                </tr>
                <tr>   
                    <td>156</td>                                                                                         
                    <td>668</td>                                                              
                    <td>100.95</td>  
                    <td>1.82</td>                                                                  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>256</td>                                                                                         
                    <td>668</td>                                                              
                    <td>100.95</td> 
                    <td>1.82</td>                                                                
                </tr>  
            </tbody> 
        </table>
        <table id='table-draggable2'>  
            <tbody class="connectedSortable">  
                <tr>
                    <th>COL1</th>  
                    <th>COL2</th>  
                    <th>COL3</th>  
                    <th>COL4</th>  
                </tr>
                <tr>   
                    <td>356</td>                                                                                         
                    <td>668</td>                                                              
                    <td>100.95</td>  
                    <td>1.82</td>                                                                  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>456</td>                                                                                         
                    <td>668</td>                                                              
                    <td>100.95</td> 
                    <td>1.82</td>                                                                
                </tr>  
            </tbody> 
        </table>
```

Comment: Where is ```.nav-tabs > li``` element in your code? Will you share more of your HTML?

Comment: @Dario i have updated with the table from the example, mine is very similar .

Comment: If I look at your HTML this selector ```$( ".nav-tabs > li", $tabs)``` returns no elements so no droppable object is initialized. Make sure that ```$( ".nav-tabs > li", $tabs).length > 0 ``` is true

Comment: @Dario thank you why is it not returning any elements? looks like the fiddle i got this from doesnt work either http://jsfiddle.net/yf47u/

Comment: There is no ```<li>``` in the HTML, same for ```.nav-tabs``` so jQuery can't just select them. I think the selector you are looking for is ```$( "#table-draggable1 tr")``` ? See here http://jsfiddle.net/tbLfz7c5/1/

Comment: cheers buddy please answer and i will except

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I look at your HTML this selector $`( ".nav-tabs > li", $tabs)` returns no elements so no droppable object is initialized.

I think the selector you are looking for is `$( "#table-draggable1 tr")`, see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tbLfz7c5/1/).

Comment: although this works if you play with the fiddle it doesnt always work as expected and the message is not displayed

Comment: It might be, my fiddle is only supposed to be just a support for bettering answer this question, not a fully complete/tested solution.